# Configurable variation is unidentifiable - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, import, csv

I'm getting the `Configurable variation is unidentifiable`  error when trying to import the configurable items to Magento 2.3.1.

I think I have the correct format for the csv, using the defined format,

```
configurable_variations
sku=WAL-WM-03-BLA-UNI,color=Negro,size=UNI|sku=WAL-WM-03-GOL-UNI,color=Dorado,size=UNI|

configurable_variation_labels
color=Color,size=Size
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the size attribute exist?

Comment: You mean the attribute itself? Yes, and the values that are present in the product also..

Answer (score 2):

Just remove "|" symbol at the end of the string. You should have:

```
sku=WAL-WM-03-BLA-UNI,color=Negro,size=UNI|sku=WAL-WM-03-GOL-UNI,color=Dorado,size=UNI
```

not

```
sku=WAL-WM-03-BLA-UNI,color=Negro,size=UNI|sku=WAL-WM-03-GOL-UNI,color=Dorado,size=UNI|
```

As it means that you have an empty option at the end

Hope that helps you